# Shifting a GDI+ texture Brush Pattern?

Tags: textures, gdi+, brush

Is there a way to shift the texture brush pattern in GDI+?  Normally the brush begins filling at (0,0) (top/left) of the widget.  I tried using negative X/Y to try to get the brush pattern to shift off the widget slightly but it does not work.  I googled this to death but found no answers.

I know this is a bit odd but I have a requirement to anchor the brush patterns at (0,0) of a root parent object, NOT at (0,0) of the widget using the brush pattern.  By doing this you get a kind of "spotlight" effect as the child widget is moved around inside the parent widget since the background pattern, no matter where the child widget is, has the effect of never moving.

Any ideas?

Comment: Shift the bitmap and create a new brush from it?

Comment: What language? C++, C# ...